# Socket hang up when using go-stomp/stomp/v3 package

Tags: go, stomp

I have the go script below and am using the github.com/go-stomp/stomp/v3/server library.

It starts, but when I try to connect to it, I get an "Socket hang up" error on the client side.

On the server side I get:

> 2023/09/12 19:53:38 ERROR: read failed: invalid command : [::1]:50266

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "net"
    "sync"
    "time"

    "github.com/go-stomp/stomp/v3"
    "github.com/go-stomp/stomp/v3/server"
)

func main() {
    // Create a TCP listener on the desired port (61613 is the default STOMP port)
    addr := ":61613"
    l, _ := net.Listen("tcp", addr)
    defer l.Close()

    // Wait for a few seconds to allow connected clients to disconnect gracefully
    var wg sync.WaitGroup

    // Start the server in a goroutine
    wg.Add(1)
    go func() {
        defer wg.Done()
        err := server.Serve(l)
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatalf("WebSocket server error: %v", err)
        }
    }()
    // Wait for a signal to stop the server (e.g., Ctrl+C)
    fmt.Printf("STOMP server is running on port %s. Press Ctrl+C to stop...\n", addr)
    wg.Wait()

    fmt.Println("STOMP server has been shut down")
}
```